# How to increment scoreboard, java fx

Tags: javafx

I am attempting to add to the scoreboard after I determine whatever player has the highest value card. The label will not update. After player 4 plays is where I assume the rest of the behind the scenes of the game takes place, i.e who has highest card, and updating score.

```
Button p4 = new Button("Player 4");
    p4.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            int n = rand.nextInt(56)+1;
            //(Double.parseDouble(card.get(n).getValue()));
            deckView4.setImage(cards.get((n)));

            p4.setDisable(true);


            array[3] = (Double.parseDouble(card.get(n).getValue()));
            Suits[3] = card.get(n).getSuit();


            if(array[0] > array[1] || array[0] > array[2] || array[0] > array[3]){

            incrementIndex1();
            }
                else if(array[1] > array[2] || array[1] > array[3]) {
                    incrementIndex2();  
                }
                else if(array[2] > array[3]) {
                    incrementIndex3();
                }
                else {
                    incrementIndex4();
                }event.consume();
            }

    });
```

Above the button code is this

```
//creates Player1 ScoresNames
    Label score1 = new Label();
    score1.setText("P1 -> ");
    score1.setPadding(new Insets(100, 0, 0, 0));

    Label score1_0 = new Label();
    score1_0.setText("" + index1 + "");
    score1_0.setPadding(new Insets(100, 0, 0, 50));

    //creates Player2 ScoreNames
    Label score2 = new Label();
    score2.setText("P2 -> ");
    score2.setPadding(new Insets(99, 0, 0, 0));

    Label score2_0 = new Label();
    score2_0.setText("" + index2 + "");
    score2_0.setPadding(new Insets(177, 0, 0, 50));

    //creates Player3 ScoreName
    Label score3 = new Label();
    score3.setText("P3 -> ");
    score3.setPadding(new Insets(98, 0, 0, 0));

    Label score3_0 = new Label();
    score3_0.setText("" + index3 + "");
    score3_0.setPadding(new Insets(252, 0, 0, 50));


    //creates Player4 ScoreName
    Label score4 = new Label();
    score4.setText("P4 -> ");
    score4.setPadding(new Insets(97, 0, 0, 0));

    Label score4_0 = new Label();
    score4_0.setText("" + index4 + "");
    score4_0.setPadding(new Insets(325, 0, 0, 50));

    //vBox for scoresNames
    VBox score = new VBox(-40);
    score.getChildren().addAll(score1,score2,score3,score4);
    score.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);


    //groups 4 players together
    g.getChildren().addAll(sp,sp1,score,h1,score1_0,score2_0, score3_0, score4_0, deckView, deckView2, deckView3, deckView4);
    //bp.setTop(t);
    bp.setCenter(g);
    //bp.setLeft(tL);
    bp.getChildren().addAll(createButtons(), vb1);
    //bp.getChildren().add(g);
```

and finally, this is initializing the above variables for incrementing the score:

```
int index1 = 00;
int index2 = 00;
int index3 = 00;
int index4 = 00;

private static ArrayList<Suit_Value> card = new ArrayList<Suit_Value>();
public static void main(String[] args) {



    cg cgg = new cg();

    cgg.readFromFile("cards");
    launch();

}
private void incrementIndex1() {
    index1++;
}
private void incrementIndex2() {
    index2++;
}
private void incrementIndex3() {
    index3++;
}
private void incrementIndex4() {
    index4++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you are trying to update the label `score1_0, score2_0` etc when `p4`button is pressed.

If my understanding is right, then you need to call the label text setters each time index is updated, like when you update `index4` then call `score4_0.setText("" + index4 + "");` each time `index4`is updated and I dont think you need `event.consume()` in your button handler.